# What is the Bible's take on the existence of dinosaurs?

Tags: bible

It seems contradictory that our school system teaches about prehistoric Dinosaurs, that roamed the earth far before humans arrived, and yet at the same time (in Catholic schools) the children are taught that God created the world equipped with human beings in seven days. Are there any official statements by the Church on this subject?

Comment: ... If you've attended a "Catholic" school that strictly taught creationism, I daresay it's not *actually* a Catholic school. The official statement of the Church is that, while a Catholic *could* interpret the creation accounts literally, "the Church" does not interpret them as such.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

It also doesn't hurt to use the "search" feature to see if your question has already been asked. A site search for the word "dinosaurs" brings up several results.

Comment: A search on "creationism" brings up many more...

Comment: The Catholic teaching on Creation starts at http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P19.HTM and includes at least the next two pages. There's a LOT.

Comment: Are you asking specifically for a Catholic point of view?

Comment: Hi, there's a serious mismatch here between the title and the body. You're asking in once place what the bible says, and in another what the church says, and in neither do you have the specificity required for a well scoped question. Add to that that we have a viable duplicate and this is just a mess.